# Duda con sesiones PHP

Tags: php, sesiones

Estoy intentando hacer sesiones con PHP y aparentemente no se me esta creando la sesión he intentado de todo y aun no se que es, alguien me podría ayudar?

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'login.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['correo'])) {
    header("Location: /proyecto/micuenta/index.php");
} else {
}
?>
```

LOGIN.PHP

```
<?php
session_start();
$correo   = $_POST["correo"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$conexion = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "oliver0303");
mysql_select_db("biciusers", $conexion);

$password  = md5($password);
$sql       = "SELECT id FROM registro WHERE correo = '$correo' AND contraseña ='$password'";
$comprobar = mysql_query($sql);
session_start();

if (mysql_num_rows($comprobar) > 0) {
    $_SESSION['correo'] = $row['correo'];

    $id = mysql_result($comprobar, 0);

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($comprobar);

    echo '<script> window.location="/proyecto/micuenta/index.php"; </script>';

} else {
    echo "usuario o contrasena invalida";
}
?>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué estás diciendo que no se crea la sesión? ¿Qué ocurre? ¿Qué debería ocurrir en cambio? ¿Qué intentaste? ... (No relacionado a tu problema: no tiene sentido llamar a `session_start()` 3 veces, es redundante, aunque no trae problemas... y al redireccionar con `header('Location: ...')` no se deben usar rutas relativas sino absolutas

Comment: `he intentado de todo` esta frase dice mucho y dice nada... debemos adivinar que has intentado??? por ejemplo intentaste implementar el sistema de sesiones de laravel o codeigniter???

Answer (score 2):

hola amigo creo que estas haciendo las cosas un poco mal estas ejecutando session_start(); sin a ver decidido nada, te paso un ejemplo para que lo adaptes a tus necesidades, creo que deberias atualizarte a PDO ya que mysql esta obsoleta

**formulario para iniciar la sesión**

```
<form  action="validar.php" name="frmContacto" method="post">

 <h6 class="left-align white-text">Usuario</h6>
 <input id='usuario' class="white-text" type="text" name="usuario" />


  <h6 class="left-align white-text">Contraseña</h6>                         
  <input id='clave' class="white-text" type="password" name="clave" 
   onkeyup="if(event.keyCode == 13) accountLogin($(this).parents('form'));" />


  <div class="center-align">
  <div class="row">

  <div class="col s12">



   <button  class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large transparent" 
   type="submit" name="guardar">Aceptar
   </button>


   <button  class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large transparent" 
   type="reset">Cancelar
   </button>


    <a href='index.php' 
    button class='btn waves-effect transparent btn-large' type='submit'>
    Inicio
    </button></a>
    </form>
```

**archivo que valida la sesión**

```
<?php
 include("conexion/conexion.php");
 // Preparamos la consulta y la ejecutamos 
 $sql = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usuario = :usuario AND 
 clave = :clave LIMIT 1');
 $sql->bindParam(':usuario', $_POST['usuario']);
 $sql->bindParam(':clave', $_POST['clave']);
 $sql->execute();
 // Comprobamos si ha devuelto algun registro
 if($sql->rowCount()>0){
  // Iniciamos sesion
   session_start();
  // Recuperamos los datos de la consulta 
  $row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 //definimos las variables necesarias para la sesion

 $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
 $_SESSION['usuario'] = $row['usuario'];
  $_SESSION['clave'] = $row['clave'];
 $_SESSION['fk_nivel_usuario'] = $row['fk_nivel_usuario'];

 //datos personales
  $_SESSION['cedula'] = $row['cedula'];
  $_SESSION['nombres'] = $row['nombres'];
  $_SESSION['apellidos'] = $row['apellidos'];
  $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
  $_SESSION['telefono'] = $row['telefono'];
  $_SESSION['direccion'] = $row['direccion'];

  // Redirigimos la pagina segun idnivel_usuario
  switch ($_SESSION['fk_nivel_usuario']) {
    case 'Administrador':
        header("Location: admin/home.php");
        exit;
        break;

    case 'Secretarias':
        header("Location: secretarias/home.php");
        exit;
        break;
    // Definimos que hacemos en caso de no detectar ningun idnivel_usuario 
    valido
    default:
        header("refresh:5;iniciar.php");
        ?>
        <div class='col s12 card-panel blue lighten-2 center'>
        <h5 class='black-text text-darken-2 center CONDENSED LIGHT5'>¡ No se 
     pudo determinar el nivel del usuario !</h5>
        </div>
        <?php
        session_destroy();
        exit;
        break;
     }

   }

  else{
header("refresh:5;iniciar.php"); 
?>
<div class='col s12 card-panel blue lighten-2 center'>
<h6 class='black-text text-darken-2 center CONDENSED LIGHT5'>¡ Ups Aviso: 
 Contraseña o usuario incorrectos !
</h6>
</div> 
<?php

 }
$sql = null;
$DB_con = null;
 ?>
```

**la sesión**

```
<!-- la session-->

    <?php

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['fk_nivel_usuario']))
  {

    header('Location: ../index.php?Error=Acceso denegado');
  echo "<script>alert('Disculpe Acceso registringido, Usuario no 
   Autorizado')</script>";

    exit(); 
  }
  ?>

 <!-- fin de la session-->
```

esto es un buen ejemplo en PDO lo que te faltaría es adaptarlos a tus necesidades, pero como te dije antes debes espesar a trabajar con PDO, suerte...